# How to Make a Discord Bot Asynchronously Wait for Reactions on Multiple Messages?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

tl;dr
**How can my bot asynchronously wait for reactions on multiple messages?**

---

I'm adding a rock-paper-scissors (rps) command to my Discord bot. Users can invoke the command can be invoked by entering `.rps` along with an optional parameter, specifying a user to play with.

```
.rps @TrebledJ
```

When invoked, the bot will direct-message (DM) the user who invoked it and the target user (from the parameter). The two users then *react* to their DM with either ✊, , or ✌️.

Now I'm trying to get this working asynchronously. Specifically, the bot will send DMs to both users (asynchronously) and wait for their reactions (asynchronously). A step-by-step scenario:

```
Scenario (Asynchronous):
1. User A sends ".rps @User_B"
2. Bot DMs User A and B.
3. User A and B react to their DMs.
4. Bot processes reactions and outputs winner.
```

<sup>(See also: Note 1)</sup>

Since the goal is to listen to wait for reactions from multiple messages, I tried  creating two separate threads/pools. Here were three attempts:

- `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`
- `multiprocessing.Pool`
- `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`

Unfortunately, all three didn't work out. (Maybe I implemented something incorrectly?)

The following code shows the command function (`rps`), a helper function (`rps_dm_helper`), and the three (unsuccessful) attempts. The attempts all make use of different helper functions, but the underlying logic is the same. The first attempt has been uncommented for convenience.

````
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool           # Attempt 1
# from multiprocessing import Pool                      # Attempt 2
# from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor    # Attempt 3


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
emojis = ['✊', '', '✌']


# Attempt 1 & 2
async def rps_dm_helper(player: discord.User, opponent: discord.User):
    if player.bot:
        return random.choice(emojis)

    message = await player.send(f"Playing Rock-Paper-Scissors with {opponent}. React with your choice.")

    for e in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(e)

    try:
        reaction, _ = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add',
                                         check=lambda r, u: r.emoji in emojis and r.message.id == message.id and u == player,
                                         timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return None

    return reaction.emoji

# # Attempt 3
# def rps_dm_helper(tpl: (discord.User, discord.User)):
#     player, opponent = tpl
#
#     if player.bot:
#         return random.choice(emojis)
#
#     async def rps_dm_helper_impl():
#         message = await player.send(f"Playing Rock-Paper-Scissors with {opponent}. React with your choice.")
#
#         for e in emojis:
#             await message.add_reaction(e)
#
#         try:
#             reaction, _ = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add',
#                                              check=lambda r, u: r.emoji in emojis and r.message.id == message.id and u == player,
#                                              timeout=60)
#         except asyncio.TimeoutError:
#             return None
#
#         return reaction.emoji
#
#     return asyncio.run(rps_dm_helper_impl())


@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, opponent: discord.User = None):
    """
    Play rock-paper-scissors!
    """

    if opponent is None:
        opponent = bot.user

    # Attempt 1: multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
    author_result = pool.apply_async(asyncio.run, args=(rps_dm_helper(ctx.author, opponent),))
    opponent_result = pool.apply_async(asyncio.run, args=(rps_dm_helper(opponent, ctx.author),))
    author_emoji = author_result.get()
    opponent_emoji = opponent_result.get()

    # # Attempt 2: multiprocessing.Pool
    # pool = Pool(processes=2)
    # author_result = pool.apply_async(rps_dm_helper, args=(ctx.author, opponent))
    # opponent_result = pool.apply_async(rps_dm_helper, args=(opponent, ctx.author))
    # author_emoji = author_result.get()
    # opponent_emoji = opponent_result.get()

    # # Attempt 3: concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
    # with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exc:
    #     author_emoji, opponent_emoji = list(exc.map(rps_dm_helper, [(ctx.author, opponent), (opponent, ctx.author)]))

    ### -- END ATTEMPTS

    if author_emoji is None:
        await ctx.send(f"```diff\n- RPS: {ctx.author} timed out\n```")
        return

    if opponent_emoji is None:
        await ctx.send(f"```diff\n- RPS: {opponent} timed out\n```")
        return

    author_idx = emojis.index(author_emoji)
    opponent_idx = emojis.index(opponent_emoji)

    if author_idx == opponent_idx:
        winner = None
    elif author_idx == (opponent_idx + 1) % 3:
        winner = ctx.author
    else:
        winner = opponent

    # send to main channel
    await ctx.send([f'{winner} won!', 'Tie'][winner is None])


bot.run(os.environ.get("BOT_TOKEN"))
````

---

**Note**

<sup>1</sup> Contrast the asynchronous scenario to a non-asynchronous one:

```
Scenario (Non-Asynchronous):
1. User A sends ".rps @User_B"
2. Bot DMs User A.
3. User A reacts to his/her DM.
4. Bot DMs User B.
5. User B reacts to his/her DM.
6. Bot processes reactions and outputs winner.
```

This wasn't too hard to implement:

````
...
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, opponent: discord.User = None):
    """
    Play rock-paper-scissors!
    """

    ...

    author_emoji = await rps_dm_helper(ctx.author, opponent)
    if author_emoji is None:
        await ctx.send(f"```diff\n- RPS: {ctx.author} timed out\n```")
        return
    
    opponent_emoji = await rps_dm_helper(opponent, ctx.author)
    if opponent_emoji is None:
        await ctx.send(f"```diff\n- RPS: {opponent} timed out\n```")
        return

    ...
````

But IMHO, the non-async makes for bad UX. :-)

Comment: So while writing this up, I realised that I could just stick to one thread/process, send two DMs, and modify the `check` function for `bot.wait_for` (since wait_for is the prevalent blocking function), then use a while-loop to check for reactions. Nonetheless, I'd still like input from the community. There's probably a better, asynchronous way of branching separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to schedule multiple coroutines to execute concurrently.  Awaiting `gather` waits for all of them to finish and returns their results as a list.

```
from asyncio import gather

@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, opponent: discord.User = None):
    """
    Play rock-paper-scissors!
    """
    if opponent is None:
        opponent = bot.user
    author_helper = rps_dm_helper(ctx.author, opponent)  # Note no "await"
    opponent_helper = rps_dm_helper(opponent, ctx.author)
    author_emoji, opponent_emoji = await gather(author_helper, opponent_helper)
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I'm presuming this uses the `async def rps_dm_helper` from Attempt 1?

Comment: Yes, but this approach would also work if you wanted to use it only on the `wait_for` calls, as those are what actually take lots of time.

Comment: Alright, I've tested `gather` but I'm getting a traceback after doing `.rps` and reacting to an emoji. I'll edit my question with the full traceback. | I've edited my question.

Comment: Oof, so after 20 releases and deploys, I think I got it — I had to `await gather(...)`.

Comment: @TrebledJ I'm sorry, that was a typo.  I fyou have the tie, you should at least skim the documentation I linked for coroutines and tasks.  Using them properly can lead to some very concise, powerful code.