# How to wait for a certain amount of time for the bot to do work?.. discord.py

Tags: python, object, async-await, discord, discord.py

I have a code that prints exactly when the user reacts to an emoji...
The code is:

```py
def check1(reaction, user):
  return user == members.users[members.leader].user and reaction.message.id == ttreact.id and str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣"

def check2(reaction,user):
  return user == members.users[members.leader].user and reaction.message.id == ttreact.id and str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣"

if len(members.users) == 2:
  reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check1)
  print("first check")
  reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check2)
  print("second check")
```

The problem is that I need the bot to print both checks after a certain amount of time from the user reacts to the specific emoji... As like:

```
Step 1: bot sends a message and adds reactions 1️⃣ and 2️⃣ to it
Step 2: user reacts to 1️⃣ innit
Step 3: user reacts to 2️⃣ into the same message
step 4: bot waits for 5 seconds
step 5: bot prints both "first check" and "second check"
```

Any ideas?

(i have done with asyncio.sleep(time) but it does wait but it only prints when the user reacts to the message after the time, not reading the past reacts and will datetime works with this trick?)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042226/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-asynchronously-wait-for-reactions-on-multiple-messages help?

Comment: Pretty sure that implements the works after the both functions comes True.. But i need the bot to work after a certain amount of time

Comment: Try using [`asyncio.gather`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622525/12451222)to run both the `wait_for`s simultaneously.

Comment: but i don't need the user to react both of em at the same time.. ```asyncio.gather``` waits for the both function to do but i need the bot to wait for not the funtions to do but a certain time

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't combine both checks in one?

Comment: i did it in one check before but i had a prob by adding the reactions innit.. Like i can only add the first reaction and not the second